# JS OnKeyDown on disabled field - Text, Select, Radio or Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Hope you can understand what i want to ask.  We can fire **OnKeyDown** on enabled element.  As well on readonly text field also.  But there is nothing like **ReadOnly** on Select or CheckBox.

```
<input type="text" id="a" onkeydown="f()" />
<input type="text" onkeydown="f()" disabled/>
<input type="text" onkeydown="f()" value="old value" ReadOnly />
```

First and Third will work. But second will not work.  When I try will same with **Select** mean with a dropdown, **ReadOnly** attribute doesn't work. To disable DropDown I have to up **disabled** attribute.  And if I use **disabled** attribute **onkeyDown** doesn't work with **disabled** element.

My Main task is to fire the **OnKeyDown** on **Disabled OR ReadOnly(** if possible **)** dropdown **Select** element.

Check the [fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Wf5qm/](http://jsfiddle.net/Wf5qm/)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. If the element is disabled then it cannot receive the focus. If it can't receive the focus, then it can't receive key events.

Comment: yes I know.. This is my problem.. I need any workaround for this.. thats why I have posted my question.. I am not saying field should be disabled only.. I want user can not change value.. its possible by readonly attribute on text box but not on Select or Checkbox Or Radio